# Angular SPA authentication with express server & passport.js -> routing issue

Tags: angular, typescript, express, passport.js

Frontend is an Angular6 SPA served by express. 
Express is used with passport.js to authenticate against an authentication provider.

Passport.js works fine - token exchange etc. works great.
My problem seems to be in the routing:

The login.html page, which is served by an authenticationGuard as part of my Angular SPA, contains an `<a href="localhost:4040/auth/provider">Login with provider</a>`

On the express side I have a

```
router.get('/auth/provider', passport.authenticate('myStrategy'));
```

and a

```
router.get('/auth/provider/callback',
  passport.authenticate('myStrategy', { failureRedirect: '../../../' }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.send('authenticated');
  }
);
```

I expected the login-link to send me to the `/auth/provider` express-route which should be caught by express and then processed with passport.js.

However, the route is caught by the angular router, which doesn't recognize it and redirects me to the login.html page.

I have seen some solutions here with `target="_self"` in the link definition, however these don't seem to work with the html5 style routing, only with hash-bang routing.

The solution of "set the `window.location='IP:port/auth/provider'`" also doesn't work - redirects to login as well.

In effect, my question is: How do I trigger an express route from within my angular6 SPA that uses html5-style routing?

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  // Fallback when no prior route is matched
  // { path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: []
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: Use `HashRouting` to avoid this confusion. can you share your `approuting.module.ts` file

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was wondering whether it is possible to do with pushState though, instead of hash-bang. Provided app-routing.

Comment: someehre you have to differentiate the routes... to avoid confusion better use `HashRouting` . And try

Comment: Tried with hash-bang routing - still no joy. When enabling tracing in the Angular Router, I get

Comment: When enabling tracing in the Angular Router, I get ``Router Event: e
NavigationStart(id: 1, url: '/')
e {id: 1, url: "/", navigationTrigger: "imperative", restoredState: null}`` which I take to mean the router receives a "/" as the url from the link...

Comment: I have tried more debugging: When I start the express server initially, I can enter the "localhost:4040/auth/provider" URL directly and it works fine - it shows a GET in the express routing log and redirects to the authentication provider. However, if I navigate to the SPA first and then manually enter the same URL, it seems to be handled directly by angular without causing a GET in the express server...